# How to use information schema for MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization

In my MySQL [InnoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InnoDB) information_schema there's a table rows number. 
When is this number updated? Maybe when I use an optimization tool?

Comment: It's updated whenever the number of rows in the table changes.

Comment: Keep in mind that the "Rows" for InnoDB tables is rarely exact; there is no way to make it exact.  The only way to get the exact number is with `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good blog post on [percona](https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/10/06/when-does-innodb-update-table-statistics-and-when-it-can-bite/) on this topic that summarises when innodb table statistics are updated along with rows_number:

- when the table is 1st opened
- when `analyse table` command is run
- when metadata commands like `SHOW INDEX`, `SHOW TABLE STATUS` and `SHOW [FULL] TABLES` (or their corresponding queries from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS) - if enabled by [innodb_stats_on_metadata](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_stats_on_metadata) setting
- when 1 / 16th of the table or 2Billion rows has been modified, whichever comes first